# listening to Mysql Table change events, for java

Tags: java, mysql

I want to listen to mysql table change using java, the most available and used way of doing this is using triggers but in mysql triggers can't do much when come to my situation,(please correct if i'm wrong)

my real scenario is this, i want to generate charts using mysql database and those charts should refresh when the mysql table is updated with a new row. so currently what i'm doing is running a separate thread watching the row count of the table and if the row count is changed then i create the chart!!!!!

but i don't think that is a good idea if there is a better way, so is there a way that i can listen to mysql table changes?

Comment: The database is updated only through your application or other independent clients can also update it ?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mysql+binary+log+&oq=mysql+binary+log+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6971j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=mysql+binlog+cdc

Answer (score 1):

Could you query the database only when a request for the charts are made? Is it outputting a picture that the user is accessing? Or is the chart being drawn in your application? If it is being drawn in your application I would just query the database when the chart is requested. Or even at timed intervals. If your data allows for it you can only request updated information from the database as well. It's hard to recommend something without knowing more about the application and data.

Comment: It's like this when the Chart is viewing by a user, another user in the network might change it!!!, i can,t use regular intervals to draw the chart because then to refresh the chart it will take some amount of time. so the first user is viewing a false output  to avoid that i have to monitor the table changes in and draw the chart  as soon as possib wnhen the table is changed

Comment: If your table has a `datetime` field attached to it you could always do a query in regular intervals for information after a certain point in time (say, the last time you received fresh data). That way you will only have to update your charts when new data comes in. If that doesn't work for you I won't be able to help you.